# Is Option GenTraversableOnce?

Tags: scala

I am confused. In `TraversableLike`, there is a function `flatMap` with the signature

`flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): Iterable[B]`

However, I can use it this way

```
scala> Iterable(1,2,3,4,5).flatMap{i=>if (i%2==0) {None} else {Some(i)}}
res1: Iterable[Int] = List(1, 3, 5)
```

Why is it possible? How is `Option` converted to `GenTraversableOnce`? It doesn't seem like a subclass...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is in fact an implicit conversion by default from Some[X] to GenTraversableOnce[X]. This is very simple to test in the REPL

```
scala>  implicitly[Function[Some[Int],GenTraversableOnce[Int]]]
res1: Some[Int] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[Int] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[Some[Int] => GenTraversableOnce[Int]] // alternative syntax
res2: Some[Int] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[Int] = <function1>
```

And in fact this is defined in the object Option. Inside scala package:

```
object Option {
  /** An implicit conversion that converts an option to an iterable value
   */
  implicit def option2Iterable[A](xo: Option[A]): Iterable[A] = xo.toList

  /** An Option factory which creates Some(x) if the argument is not null,
   *  and None if it is null.
   *
   *  @param  x the value
   *  @return   Some(value) if value != null, None if value == null
   */
  def apply[A](x: A): Option[A] = if (x == null) None else Some(x)

  /** An Option factory which returns `None` in a manner consistent with
   *  the collections hierarchy.
   */
  def empty[A] : Option[A] = None
}
```

option2Iterable is exactly what you are looking for. You can also see why when testing in your REPL you could see that the implementation of GenTraversableOnce is a list.

If you are looking for implicit conversions which are automatically imported without you doing anything ( like the one you can see in the REPL using implicitly) you have to look at:

- Predef.scala
- Companion objects of the class

Comment: "This is very simple to test in the REPL" `implicitly[Function[Some[Int],GenTraversableOnce[Int]]]` -__- straightforward, yes, but that's an awful lot of square brackets to be calling "simple" imho.

Comment: For dan: scala>  import scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce
import scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce

scala>  type OptionToTraversableConversion[X] = Function[ Option[X], GenTraversableOnce[X] ]
defined type alias OptionToTraversableConversion

scala>  implicitly[OptionToTraversableConversion[Int]]
res3: Option[Int] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[Int] = <function1>

Answer (score 20):

As you can see in the class diagram(*), `Option` is not a subclass of `GenTraversableOnce`, but there's a implicit conversion available to `Iterable`, which is a `GenTraversableOnce`.

[image]

(*) Yeah, ok, I cheated. Class diagrams are not available on Scaladoc yet... but they should be tomorrow! :-)

Comment: Visually illustrates pretty well what's going on! This in combination with Edmondo's answer should be accepted (and Karel's is simpler but provides more evidence as well)

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Sure, but there's nothing stopping you from look at 2.10's scaladoc for your 2.9.2 needs. It will be the same most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like it is indeed implicitly converted to `List`.

```
scala> val l:scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[Int] = Some(3)
l: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[Int] = List(3)

scala> val l:scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[Int] = None
l: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[Int] = List()
```

personal note: scala magic implicit conversions are sometimes really confusing.