# difference between map and flatMap in scala

Tags: scala

what is the difference between map and flatMap? As in we can do a

```
1 to 5 map(c => println(c))
```

but not

```
1 to 5 flatMap(c => println(c))
```

On the other hand, this works

```
def h(i: Int) = if (i >= 2) Some(i) else None
1 to 5 flatMap(h)
```

I understand that flatMap is map and flatten, but not sure when a map can be used and when a flatMap can be used.

Comment: [Map versus FlatMap on String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209519/map-versus-flatmap-on-string) answer your question

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997900/apache-spark-comparison-of-map-vs-flatmap-vs-mappartitions-vs-mappartitionswith

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's see the signature of [flatMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html#flatMap[B](f:A=>scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B]):scala.collection.TraversableOnce[B]).

```
def flatMap[B](f: (Int) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): TraversableOnce[B]
```

and the signature of [map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html#map[B](f:A=>B):scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[B])

```
def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): IndexedSeq[B]
```

You can see that the result type of `f` must be `GenTraversableOnce[B]` for `flatMap`.
but there's no restriction in the result type of `f` for `map`.

The result type of `println(x)` is `Unit` and result type of `x+2` is `Int`. Since both does not implement `GenTraversableOnce[B]`, you cannot do `flatMap(x=>println(x))` nor `flatMap(x=>x+2)`.

On the other hand `Some(i)` and `None` have type of `Option[Int]`, which can be implicitly converted to `Iterable[Int]` [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.2/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L17)

The signature of [Iterable](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html) is

```
trait Iterable[+A] extends Traversable[A]
```

and [Traversable](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Traversable.html) is

```
trait Traversable[+A] .. with TraversableOnce[A]`
```

and finally [TraversableOnce](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.html) is

```
trait TraversableOnce[+A] extends GenTraversableOnce[A]
```

hence `Option[Int]` implements `GenTraversableOnce[Int]` so you can use it as result of `flatMap[Int]`

Answer (score 1):

The error is:

> Type mismatch, expected: (int) => GenTraverableOnce[NotInferedB],
>   actual: (int) => Unit

Because `flatMap` is a combination of `map` and `flatten`. So `flatMap` will runs map on every element of sequence, and then run flatten.

For example: `[1,2][2,3]` --> `[1,2,2,3]`

Scala cannot do that with type Unit. Technically because Unit doesn't implement `GenTraverableOnce`. `Option` doesn't either, but `Option[A]` can be implicit converted to `Iterable[A]`, which is `GenTraverableOnce[A]`. Here is the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429360/is-option-gentraversableonce)

Comment: thanks for the help. Why does this not work then flatMap(x => x + 2) where as map(x => x + 2) works? Maybe you already mentioned it, but I do not get the answer.

Comment: `flatMap(x => x + 2)` still not work, because the signature at this time is: `flatMap[Int, Int]`. But Int doesn't implement `GenTraversableOnce`. `map` doesn't have this restriction. You can map from arbitrary type A to arbitrary type B.

Comment: you can `flatMap(x => Some(x))` because at this time, `flatMap` signature is `flatMap[Int, Option]`.  But `Option[A]` can be implicit converted to `GenTraverableOnce[A]`. You can see on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429360/is-option-gentraversableonce