# Scala 'type mismatch error' while using a function but works fine for method

Tags: scala

```
def stringToIntMethod(input:String):Option[Int] = {
  try{
    Some(Integer.parseInt(input.trim()))
  }
  catch{
    case e:Exception => None
  }
}

val stringToIntFunction: (String) => Option[Int] = (in:String) => {
  try{
    Some(Integer.parseInt(in.trim()))
  }
  catch{
    case e:Exception => None
  }
}

val stringAndIntArray = Array("Hello", "1","2","Hi") //Input

println("with Method is: " + stringAndIntArray.flatMap(stringToIntMethod))
println("with functon is: " + stringAndIntArray.flatMap(stringToIntFunction))
```

getting a type mismatch error while using stringToIntFunction in flatMap

```
type mismatch;
  found   : String => Option[Int]
  required: String => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
println("with functon is: " + stringAndIntArray.flatMap(stringToIntFunction))
                                                    ^
```

Why is it?

Answer (score 2):

`flatMap` requires lambda, you are passing it a normal method

Here is the fix

```
stringAndIntArray.flatMap(stringToIntMethod _)
```

## Scala REPL

```
scala> def toInt(s: String): Option[Int] = Some(s.toInt)
toInt: (s: String)Option[Int]

scala> Array("1", "2", "3").flatMap(toInt _)
res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Normal method can be converted to lambda using underscore

## More examples for clarity

```
scala> def foo(s: String, i: Int): Double = 1
foo: (s: String, i: Int)Double

scala> foo _
res2: (String, Int) => Double = $$Lambda$1162/1477996447@62faf77

scala> foo(_, _)
res3: (String, Int) => Double = $$Lambda$1168/1373527802@30228de7


scala> foo(_: String, _: Int)
res5: (String, Int) => Double = $$Lambda$1183/477662472@2adc1e84


scala> foo("cow", _: Int)
res7: Int => Double = $$Lambda$1186/612641678@146add7b

scala> foo("Cow is holy", _: Int)
res8: Int => Double = $$Lambda$1187/1339440195@7d483ebe
```

Also adding a comment from lambda. xy. x

```
f _ is syntactic sugar for f(_) which is again syntactic sugar for x => f(x)
```

Comment: Perhaps a small elaboration on the underscore: `f _` is syntactic sugar for `f(_)` which is again syntactic sugar for `x => f(x)`.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x Thanks for input!

Comment: Also that is called 'eta expansion' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445018/what-is-the-eta-expansion-in-scala

Comment: I want to use **stringToIntFunction**, not  stringToIntMethod, even without _ or lambda conversation it works fine.

Comment: @Omprakash Yes, because its a lambda (function)

Comment: @ccheneson to be precise, eta expansion is the automatic conversion from `f` to `λx f(x)` due to extensionality. This would be an explicit eta expansion that does not rely on extensionality.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still puzzled myself about why this example does not work. I assume it has to do with Scala's type inference. If you look at the error message

```
 found   : String => Option[Int]
 required: String => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
```

it says that the return value of stringToIntFunction does not fit the argument value of `flatMap`. Indeed, the type test

```
Some(1).isInstanceOf[TraversableOnce[Int]]
```

leads to:

```
<console>:138: warning: fruitless type test: a value of type Some[Int] cannot also be a scala.collection.TraversableOnce[Int] (the underlying of TraversableOnce[Int])
  Some(1).isInstanceOf[TraversableOnce[Int]]
                      ^
res24: Boolean = false
```

Funnily enough, when I change the return type of your function to`TraversableOnce[Int]`, it works:

```
def stringToIntFunction : String => TraversableOnce[Int] = (in:String) => {
   //...
}
```

leads to

```
scala> stringAndIntArray.flatMap(stringToIntFunction)
res28: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2)
```

The reason is that even though `Option` does not derive from `TraversableOnce`, there is an implicit conversion:

```
 scala> def f(to : TraversableOnce[Int]) = to.size
 f: (to: TraversableOnce[Int])Int
 scala> f(Some(1))
 res25: Int = 1
```

This has also been noticed in a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429360/is-option-gentraversableonce/11429894) before.

My theory is that for a method the return value is explicitly known to the compiler which allows it to detect the presence of an implicit conversion from `Option[Int] => TraversableOnce[Int]`. But in the case of a function value the compiler would only look for an implicit conversion between `(String => Option[Int]) => (String => TraversableOnce[Int])`. When the lambda application `stringToIntFunction _` is passed instead, the compiler seems to see that it can apply the implicit conversion again.

Comment: Changing the return type to Traversable is not a good idea though because it contains an implicit conversion. Better directly return  `List(Integer.parseInt(in.trim()))` then.

Comment: Yep, makes sense. Thanks.